# Eclipse plugin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-plugin

As you can see:

[image]

I added `jni4net.j-0.8.6.0.jar` to my referenced libraries but I still receive a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jni4net/Bridge
    at sibeclipseplugin.debug.DebuggerInterface.initialize(DebuggerInterface.java:15)
    at sibeclipseplugin.debug.SibDebugTarget.<init>(SibDebugTarget.java:65)
    at sibeclipseplugin.ui.launch.LaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge cannot be found by SIBEclipsePlugin_0.0.0.1
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

I have no idea what the problem is. When I start the project as Eclipse-Application it can't find that class. Running the same code in a normal Java-Project works.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I think one of the jar is in the system classpath, which eclipse can't see. If it's possible, move that jar also in the project classpath.

Comment: If this is a web application, drop the jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. Otherwise, I recommend creating a folder inside your project (I tend to call it lib) and drop the jars there, then make reference to this folder and all the jars there as part of the build path.

Comment: Hell yeah, you're right. I didn't think about that! Maybe you could telle this too: I have a .dll-file which the debugged Eclipse-Application is in the need of. Is there a way to tell the eclipse plugin to export the .dll file that I already copied into my project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the jar files in your build.properties bin.includes entry. Also, in your MANIFEST.MF file, they need to be added in the Runtime->Classpath list (corresponds to the Bundle-ClassPath entry in the MANIFEST.MF).

Edit: if you just put them in the referenced libraries, the OSGi system will not be aware of that fact.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue with my .jar in my Referenced Libraries folder (jar was added via right click project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Libraries --> Add External Jar).

**This fixed it: right click project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Order and Export.  Make sure your .jar file is checked.**  This adds it to the build class path.  You'd think this would be automatically checked after first adding the .jar via the above method but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

This may also happen if your jar file is dependent on some other jar files for their woking and you have not added them in your project.

Answer (score 2):

It is not marked to export in the project properties:
"Project Properties" > "Order and Export" tab > make sure the .jar file is checked for export.