# Eclipse Plugin - adding a jar used by eclipse itself

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar

I'm trying to write an Eclipse-Plugin using Eclipse. The plugin uses org.eclipse.jdt.core.
At some point in my code, I'm getting an object of CompilcationUnit from the menus-action-handlers, and I want to find the java-file's path that was clicked on using my plugin.

At first, on the line getting an object of type "CompilcationUnit", I got a NoClassDefFoundError (I referenced the org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar that was in my eclipse/plugins folder).
This thread solved that issue:
[Eclipse plugin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105361/eclipse-plugin-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Similar solution found it:
[Java eclipse : Importing jar file in eclipse plugin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911465/java-eclipse-importing-jar-file-in-eclipse-plugin-project)

Now, I have a different error. I'm trying to verify the element is of type CompilationUnit and then use it.
I wrote the following code:

```
System.out.println(element.getClass());
System.out.println(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.class);

System.out.println(element instanceof org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit);
    
System.out.println(element.getClass().getPackage());
System.out.println(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.class.getPackage());

System.out.println(element.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
System.out.println(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cu = (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit)element;
```

The output is this:

> class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit
>
> class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit
>
> false
>
> package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core
>
> package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core
>
> file:/C:/Program Files/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.1.v20150902-1521.jar
>
> file:/D:/Svn/OrderingTR/Source/ClassMethodsRearranger/external/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.1.v20150902-1521.jar

And then I get an exception:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit
```

I do not understand this. It seems the element is of the same type that my code is referencing. Only my code references the type in ile:/D:/Svn/OrderingTR/Source/ClassMethodsRearranger/external/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.1.v20150902-1521.jar

and the element is of the same type of the same jar, only located in file:/C:/Program Files/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.1.v20150902-1521.jar.

Now, I need to reference the file in D:/Svn/... because that is the project's jar, and it is needed for eclipse plugins (otherwise I get the NoClassDefFoundError solved earlier).
But I am unable to use the element I get from the menu-actions-handlers (I believe because it originated in a different jar file). I need to use that element.
What can I do? Has someone encountered this kind of problem? I searched and searched and found nothing on the subject... It seems it is specific to eclipse plugins and using the jdt.core.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate the long read.

Comment: I solved it with reflection. Instead of using the references (which throw exceptions) I am calling methods via reflection, until the code is no longer in the jdt.core package.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved it by adding the reference in the MANIFEST.MF.
At the dependencies, I added org.eclipse.jdt.core in the Required Plug-ins.